# Having multiple tables for the same entity using EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 sibling entities (`Child1` & `Child2`) inheriting from a base class (`Parent`) and sharing some entities (`SubEntity`) :

```cs
class SubEntity {}
class Parent {
   SubEntity SE { get; set; }
}
class Child1 : Parent {}
class Child2 : Parent {}
```

`Child1` and `Child2` are mapped to 2 distinct tables `table-child1` and `table-child2`.

In the SubEntity entity config, I have :

```cs
class SubEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SubEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("table-child1-se");
    }
}
```

How can I map `SubEntity` to 2 dinstinct tables `table-child1-se` and `table-child2-se`?

Comment: Is there a _good reason_ you're using inheritance in your domain model?

Comment: Basically to avoid code duplication

Comment: Inheritance is not intended to reduce code-duplication (that's a common misconception). Besides, [inheritance-based OOP is a bad idea overall](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/) - _mixins_ are are you solve the class-member-duplication problem, however (annoyingly) C#/.NET does not support true mixins yet, but that doesn't mean inheritance should be abused simply to eliminate redefining common members.

Comment: This is not only to eliminate redefining common members, this is also to avoid exactly same processings accros sibling classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are different tables, you need to use different classes, otherwise how would you expect this query to work, which table would it use?:

```
var data = context.Set<SubEntity>().ToList();
```

If you need to reuse that base class, then you could consider using a combination of generics and inheritance. For example:

```
abstract class BaseSubEntity {} // Make it abstract to be safer
class Child1SubEntity : BaseSubEntity {}
class Child2SubEntity : BaseSubEntity {}

class Parent<TSubEntity>
   : where TSubEntity : BaseSubEntity
{
   TSubEntity SE { get; set; }
}

class Child1 : Parent<Child1SubEntity> {}
class Child2 : Parent<Child2SubEntity> {}
```